# Can we use Azkaban with Google Cloud Bigtable?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, azkaban

Can we use Azkaban with Google Cloud Bigtable, as we do with Apache HBase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we [search for `"hbase"` in the Azkaban GitHub repo](https://github.com/azkaban/azkaban/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=hbase&type=), it shows no results, which suggests that it does not link against HBase directly, but just schedules jobs. Thus, it should work just as well to schedule jobs with Bigtable backend as well.

If you do try it out, and run into any issues, please post specific questions with error logs so that we can help you further.

Comment: Thanks @Misha Brukman, will provide error logs if we get any issues.